# como preguntar por un dispositivo usb con un espacio de 32gb y realizar una acción al desctarla en linux

Tags: mysqli

Buen día tengo la siguiente tarea necesito copiar archivos de una camara a un HDD ambos conectados en el mismo equipo planeo hacer backups automáticos al ingresar la cámara y que los sincronice al HDD que tengo conectado al equipo.

Buscando por internet encontre que rsync soluciona la parte de la sincronía, por otra parte no se como preguntar por la microSD su capacidad es de 32gb y su formato es fat32.

Encontre un pequeño script que dice lo siguiente

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# -*- ENCODING: UTF-8 -*-
# Este programa es software libre. Puede redistribuirlo y/o
# modificarlo bajo los términos de la Licencia Pública General
# de GNU según es publicada por la Free Software Foundation,
# bien de la versión 2 de dicha Licencia o bien (según su
# elección) de cualquier versión posterior.
#
# Si usted hace alguna modificación en esta aplicación,
# deberá siempre mencionar al autor original de la misma.
#
# Copyleft 2012, DesdeLinux.net {Ciudad Habana, Cuba}.
# Autor: KZKG^Gaara <kzkggaara@desdelinux.net> <http://desdelinux.net>

CONTROL=0
PLACE="/home/media/pi/toshiba"

mkdir $PLACE
chmod 777 -R $PLACE

while [ $CONTROL=0 ] ; do
    cat /etc/mtab | grep media >> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        CONTROL=0
    else
        CONTROL=1
        for USBDEV in `df | grep media | awk -F / {'print $5'}` ;
        do
            USBSIZE=`df | grep $USBDEV | awk {'print $2'}`
            if [ $USBSIZE -lt 15664800 ]; then
                USBNAME=`echo $USBDEV | awk -F / {'print $3'}`
                mkdir $PLACE/$USBNAME
                rsync /media/$USBNAME/ $PLACE/$USBNAME/ -ahv --include-from=/opt/bash/usb-spy.files --exclude=*.* --prune-empty-dirs
            fi
        done
    fi
    sleep 5
done

exit 0
```

Copia perfectamente los archivos pero los copia al hdd local(donde están cargados los archivos de arranque el home y esas cosas), el problema es que cuando ingreso el HDD de respaldo al ejecutarlo desde la terminal me aparece un mensaje con la siguiente leyenda "too many arguments"

ahora segui pensando y entiedo que los ciclo IF son para condicionar la siguiete accion lo que no doy es como preguntar específicamente por mi microSD porque entiendo que no sabe que dispositvo sincronizar, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola Héctor, me parece un ejercicio interesante para aprender a trabajar con udev. Me pongo a trabajar con ello, te respondo cuando consiga algo en condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dije en el comentario, vamos a utilizar [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) para resolver esta tarea. Los siguientes comandos los deberás hacer como *root*, ya que vamos a tocar el sistema a bajo nivel:

**Parte 1: Identificar tarjeta SD**

Insertamos la tarjeta SD en nuestro equipo y lanzamos el siguiente comando:

```
fdisk -l
```

Muy seguramente, si tienes un disco duro interno (**sda**) y uno externo (**sdb**) conectados permanentemente a tu ordenador, te identifique la tarjeta como **sdc**. [fdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdisk) mostrará información sobre las particiones de todos ellos. En cualquier caso, quédate con la que corresponda por tamaño:

> Disco /dev/sdc: 29,8 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, ...

**NOTA**: De aquí en adelante voy a suponer que sdc es el nombre que asigna tu sistema a dicha tarjeta.

**Parte 2: Configurar udev**

Una vez estemos seguros de que nuestra tarjeta está identificada por el sistema como /dev/sdc, desmontamos su partición (por si acaso):

```
umount /dev/sdc1
```

A continuación, vamos a quedarnos con el **número de serie** de la tarjeta (es el único elemento imposible de repetir). Nos servirá un poco más adelante para que el script de copia solo se lance cuando metas esa SD y no otra:

```
udevadm info -a -n sdc | grep serial | head -n 1
```

Arrojará una salida como la siguiente:

> ATTRS{serial}=="1234567890ABCDEF"

Apúntalo. Ahora nos vamos al siguiente directorio:

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

Con el editor de textos que más nos guste (usaré [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)), creamos un fichero llamado `sd.rules` (el nombre importa poco, pero que acabe en `.rules`):

```
nano sd.rules
```

Una vez en ese fichero, añadiremos el siguiente contenido (ojo al número de serie, es el que conseguimos antes):

```
KERNEL=="sd*1", ATTRS{serial}=="1234567890ABCDEF", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/backup.sh"
```

Para guardarlo y salir al mismo tiempo: en *nano* es `Ctrl+X`, `S`, y la tecla `Intro`.

**Parte 3: Probar que funciona**

Si te fijas, en el apartado anterior hemos conseguido que cada vez que insertes la SD lance un comando en concreto. Antes de meter el script de backup, vamos a probarlo:

```
nano /usr/local/bin/backup.sh
```

Dentro de ese nuevo fichero, introducimos lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script que añade el texto "Tarjeta SD insertada." (sin las comillas)
# al fichero /tmp/log_prueba.txt
echo "Tarjeta SD insertada." >> /tmp/log_prueba.txt
exit 0
```

Para guardarlo y salir al mismo tiempo: en *nano* es `Ctrl+X`, `S`, y la tecla `Intro`. Por último, le daremos permisos de ejecución:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backup.sh
```

En este punto, si sacas y metes tu tarjeta SD, debería de crearse automáticamente un fichero en `/tmp` llamado `log_prueba.txt` con el texto especificado. Antes de seguir adelante, prueba a extraer la SD y a introducirla dos o tres veces: observarás que el fichero crece en tamaño y añade una línea en cada acción.

**Parte 4: Configurar script de copia**

Aquí ya es a gusto de cada uno, aunque reconozco que el siguiente programa debería funcionar sin problemas.

```
nano /usr/local/bin/backup.sh
```

Dentro de ese fichero, borramos lo que haya e introducimos lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script que hace copia de seguridad entre dos carpetas del sistema.

# RUTAS:
SD="/dev/sdc1"
HDD="/dev/sdb1"
ORIGEN="/home/media/pi/sd/"
DESTINO="/home/media/pi/toshiba/"

# Creamos los puntos de montaje y les damos permisos:
mkdir -p $ORIGEN $DESTINO
chmod 777 -R $ORIGEN $DESTINO

# Montamos los dispositivos en sus puntos de montaje:
mount $SD $ORIGEN
mount $HDD $DESTINO

# Lanzamos la copia con rsync:
rsync -avzh --delete $ORIGEN $DESTINO

# Desmontamos los medios:
umount $ORIGEN $DESTINO

exit 0
```

Puedes adaptarlo tu gusto, espero que este manual te haya servido.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo estoy haciendo pruebas y modifican dolo a mis necesidadescompartire el resultado cuando lo tenga.

Comment: Ok Héctor, no te olvides de marcar como válido si te sirvió. Saludos.